# SpringBoot JPA 2.1 Converter ignores convertToDatabaseColumn

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, converters, jpa-2.1

I have the following converter

```
import javax.persistence.AttributeConverter;
import javax.persistence.Converter;

@Converter(autoApply = true)
public class ImportedReasonConverter implements AttributeConverter<ImportedReason, String> {
    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(final ImportedReason pImportedReason) {
        return pImportedReason.getValue();
    }

    @Override
    public ImportedReason convertToEntityAttribute(final String pImportedReason) {
        return ImportedReason.of(pImportedReason);
    }
}
```

which is used by an entity such as

```
@Entity
@Table(
        name = "IMPORT_RECORD"
)
public class ImportRecordEntity implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2483327758356663412L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private UUID id;

    @Column(name = "importedReason")
    private ImportedReason importedReason;

    public ImportedReason getImportedReason() {
        return importedReason;
    }

    public void setImportedReason(final ImportedReason importedReason) {
        this.importedReason = importedReason;
    }

{...}
}
```

Upon starting the application, the table gets created by Hibernate, using the correct column type (here: VARCHAR). Removing the autoApply=true setting leads to a startup failure - so the converter itself is recognized.

But: upon saving the entity w/ a value set to importedReason, I get a

```
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: ImportedReason
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1185)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1553)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1510)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1433)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1179)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:349)
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper.serialize(SerializationHelper.java:115)
    ... 43 more
```

Try to debug my converter, method ImportedReasonConverter.convertToDatabaseColumn(ImportedReason) does not get called. Therefore Hibernate does not try to write the value of type String but type ImportedReason.

Any idea, why the converter does not get used properly? I have tried it with Java 8 + 11 and Spring 2.1.5.RELEASE + 2.1.9.RELEASE (the earlier versions used to work with another project).
I have also tried it with some other converters (e.g. internal type -> LocalDateTime), but I have the same issue here as well.

Thanks a lot.
Stefan

Comment: '@Column(name = "importedReason")
@Converter(.......)
private ImportedReason importedReason;'

Comment: @Zorglube no, that doesnt change it

Comment: Really !?  Weird, is your annotation look like that ? `@Convert(converter = ImportedReasonConverter.class)`, did the debug show you pssing throught the `convertToDatabaseColumn`, `convertToEntityAttribute` method ?

Comment: I tried both, setting autoApply = true on the converter itself and adding @Converter at the Entity's attribute. Both ways the Converter seems to be used (the table is setup correctly), but when it comes to using it for referenced Entities its gets kind of invisible.
Please see my Answer - I tried to describe it there in more detail.

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**
further investigation showed, that the Entity, which is being saved, is fully analyzed and its converters get used properly.
**But:** if that Entity uses yet some other Entity as reference, which in turn uses types to be converted using those converters: that's when it sees the values but does not employ the converter (for some reason).

So my ImportRecordEntity from above is used in the following PortfolioEntity, which I'm actually trying to save. Saving the ImportRecordEntity works with no hassle. I then set this ImportRecordEntity instance (returned from the save-method) to the PortfolioEntity instance and save it. But then Hibernate crashes, because it seems like it has analyzed PortfolioEntity but not ImportRecordEntity which holds the ImportedReason - so it doesn't know about the ImportedReasonConverter (see org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(Object, EntityKey, EntityPersister, boolean, Object, EventSource, boolean) - AbstractSaveEventListener.java:122 variable types).

```
@Entity
@Table(
        name = "PORTFOLIO"
)
public class PortfolioEntity implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3632725596750538287L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private UUID id;

    @Column(name = "IMPORT_RECORD")
    private ImportRecordEntity importRecord;

{...}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh my... this is soo dump...

I forgot that this is a @OneToOne mapping

My Entities need to be set up as follows:

```
@Entity
@Table(
        name = "PROVIDER_PORTFOLIO"
)
public class PortfolioEntity implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3632725596750538287L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private UUID id;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(
            name = "IMPORT_RECORD_ID"
    )
    private ImportRecordEntity importRecord;
[...]
}

@Entity
@Table(
        name = "IMPORT_RECORD"
)
public class ImportRecordEntity implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2483327758356663412L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private UUID id;

    @Column(name = "importedReason")
    private ImportedReason importedReason;
[...]
}
```

well...sorry for the confusion, should have just stopped working ;)

Stefan